# Client project issue

Tags: sql

https://www.scribd.com/document/437747149/SQL-Questions . I have worked the solution but not can't get the desired output .

My work so far

```
SELECT  Account_ID,Account_Name,Count(*) 
FROM  users Account_ID ,training_db 
Where  users.Account_ID = training_db.Account_ID
AND Training_Date = 
(SELECT Training_Date FROM  training_db ) 
GROUP BY Account_ID
Having Count(*)>1
ORDER BY  Training_Date_DESC
```

Any help will be highly helpful

Comment: Edit your question such that there's no need to navigate away from this page in order to answer it.

Comment: Why have you tagged 3 completely different RDBMS..?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.ome
     , s.tuff
  FROM users u 
  JOIN training_db t 
    ON t.something = u.something 
 GROUP 
    BY s.ome
     , s.tuff
HAVING COUNT(a.nother_thing) > 1 
 ORDER 
    BY s.ome
     , o.ther_stuff DESC;
```